# PHPMYADMIN not loading in Ubuntu12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have installed phyMyAdmin on my Ubuntu 12.04 using sudo apt-get.. I configured the Apache2 Server as it was given in the Documentation The problem I am facing is that when i take `"http://localhost/phyMyAdmin"` nothing is displayed in the browser,instead it downloads a php file. Why is this occuring?How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing PHP.

From the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql`

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can then navigate to `http://localhost/phyMyAdmin` and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf

sudo service apache2 restart